# SMS Link for Mobile APP Download

Tags: sms, redirect

We have developed mobile apps having invite friends option. This functionality has option to send SMS to a friend for invite. We have the phone number and the name of the user to whom invite is to be sent and no device info. I want to create a generic link on clicking which should redirect user to play store app link if the device is Android and to app store app link if device is IOS. Solutions that I have thought of are as below:

- Deploy a web page having javascript which detects the device OS
  (browser can do that) and then redirect user further to appropriate
  store.
- Redirecting the user to the website of the app where there are links to both the stores.

Except the above two is there a way that I can create a generic link in SMS redirect the user directly to appropriate store?

Comment: im not sure what you need help with here.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Do you know any other solution apart from what I have thought of?

Comment: when doing thinks like this, i often refer to the KISS approach. set up a short link, such as the google shortlink (which remain active for extended time) then just embed that link in messages.